# yeoman framework with many different applications

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, bower, enyo

I love yo framework for single page application. Now i would like to create more application under one yo framework so i would require one grunt file. Let say i am using angular bootplate for front end web as single application app, now i want to add a application based on enyo app using enyo bootplate. How would i add new enyo app in existing framework so i can have the app2 to load from main web when called by user? What is the best practices for multi-app framework like this?

Here is my current yo structure

```
.
├── Gruntfile.js
├── README.md
├── app
│   ├── 404.html
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── images
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── pages
│   ├── robots.txt
│   ├── scripts
│   └── styles
├── bower.json
├── bower_components
│   ├── a0-angular-storage
│   ├── angular
    ......
├── config
│   ├── config.js
│   └── environments
├── dist
│   ├── 404.html
│   ├── bower_components
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── images
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── pages
│   ├── robots.txt
│   ├── scripts
│   └── styles
├── node_modules
│   ├── generator-env-config
    ........
│   └── yo
├── notes.txt
├── package.json
└── test
    ├── karma.conf.js
    └── spec
```

This is what i think i have to change to.

```
├── Gruntfile.js
├── README.md
├── app
│   ├── 404.html
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── images
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── pages
│   ├── robots.txt
│   ├── scripts
│   └── styles
│   ├── app2
│       ├── Gruntfile.js
│       ├── README.md
│       ├── assets
│       ├── bower.json
│       ├── debug.html
│       ├── deploy.json
│       ├── deploy.md
│       ├── enyo
│       ├── icon.png
│       ├── index.html
│       ├── lib
│       ├── node_modules
│       ├── package.js
│       ├── package.json
│       ├── source
│       ├── tasks
│       └── tools
├── bower.json
├── bower_components
│   ├── a0-angular-storage
│   ├── angular
    ......
├── config
│   ├── config.js
│   └── environments
├── dist
│   ├── 404.html
│   ├── bower_components
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── images
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── pages
│   ├── robots.txt
│   ├── scripts
│   └── styles
├── node_modules
│   ├── generator-env-config
    ........
│   └── yo
├── notes.txt
├── package.json
└── test
    ├── karma.conf.js
    └── spec
```

Comment: it's not a framework, it's a scaffolding tool. you can use it for whatever framework you wish to use.

Comment: can you suggest one which uses grunt?